# Add swipe gesture to UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

How would I make it so that one gesture anywhere on a UITableView would do something?

Not just within one cell, but anywhere on the screen (a horizontal swipe)?

Comment: check this:http://maniacdev.com/2013/03/open-source-control-for-easily-creating-swipe-gesture-responsive-animated-uitableview-cells and http://www.jademind.com/blog/posts/swipe-gestures-on-uitableview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    //There is a direction property on UISwipeGestureRecognizer. You can set that to both right and left swipes
    recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [tableView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];

}
```

**Finally**

Just return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` in your `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it dead simple using the interface builder you can apply the gesture on a ViewController that contains only the TableView and show that ViewController inside a container.